# Asociar a una variable divs que están dentro de una section

Tags: javascript, variables

Necesito asociar a una variable tres divs que se encuentran en una section, y que a su vez uno está dentro de otro..

```
<section class="flujo-eventos">
  <div class="uno">
    1
    <div class="dos">
      2
      <div class="tres">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

El problema que los quiero guardar en una variable desde mi archivo JavasCript, pero luego de hacerlo; imprimo en la consola dicha variable y lo que me trae es un NodeList vacío. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Este es mi documento js:

```
const $divsEventos = document.querySelectorAll('eventos-flujo div');
console.log($divsEventos) 
//NodeList []length: 0[[Prototype]]: NodeList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un par de problemas que deberías corregir para conseguir lo que te propones:

1. La clase que estás usando para el selector no existe en tu HTML. Estás usando **eventos-flujo** cuando debería ser **flujo-eventos**.
2. La función `querySelectorAll()` usa selectores CSS para referenciar a los elementos del DOM, por lo que el nombre de la clase debe ir precedido de un punto.

```js
const $divsEventos = document.querySelectorAll('.flujo-eventos div');
console.log($divsEventos)
```

```html
<section class="flujo-eventos">
  <div class="uno">
    1
    <div class="dos">
      2
      <div class="tres">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Referencia:** [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)